# How to hidden / delete data in row if same from the top

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I have table transaction from mysql query like this.

```
 ____________________________________________________________
 | id | noskom      | nonpbm     |    noskop   |    npbp     |
 |____|_____________|____________|_____________|_____________|
 |  1 | 001         |   10       |       20    |       20    |
 |  2 | 001         |   20       |       10    |       20    |
 |  3 | 002         |    5       |       10    |       20    |
 |  4 | 003         |   30       |        5    |       20    |
 |____|_____________|____________|_____________|_____________|
```

and i want result

```
 select sum(nonpbm),sum(noskop),sum(npbp) from transaction group by noskom

 ____________________________________________________________
 | id | noskom      | nonpbm     |    noskop   |    npbp     |
 |____|_____________|____________|_____________|_____________|
 |  1 | 001         |   30       |       30    |       40    |
 |  2 |             |            |             |             |
 |  3 | 002         |    5       |       10    |       20    |
 |  4 | 003         |   30       |        5    |       20    |
 |____|_____________|____________|_____________|_____________|
```

what is mysql query

Comment: why do you want second record null

Comment: @suresh.g: That's very neat. But you do realise this is just an example, don't you? In reality, the OP may not actually know which ID to compare to in order to blank the values, and it may well be more than one ID for that matter.

Comment: @AndriyM - But we need some identity for delete particular row...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select transaction.id,t.noskom,t.sum_nonpbm,t.sum_noskop,t.sum_npbp
from transaction
left join 
(
   select noskom, min(id) min_id, 
               sum(nonpbm) sum_nonpbm,
               sum(noskop) sum_noskop,
               sum(npbp) sum_npbp 
   from transaction 
   group by noskom
) t on (transaction.id=t.min_id)
order by transaction.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    noskom , 
    SUM(nonpbm) as nonpbm , 
    sum(noskop) as noskop , 
    sum(npbp) as  npbp
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY noskom
```

If you want to list the IDs of all the rows that contributed to the aggregated values, you can also add this column:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) AS id
```

This will give you a comma-separated list of IDs. You can specify a different separator, like EOL:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id SEPARATOR '\r\n') AS id
```

`'\r\n'` is the standard line separator in the Windows world. Change to just `'\n'` or `'\r'` if you are on a different platform.

Comment: Did you mean `GROUP BY noskom`?

Comment: group by any which is being sum

Comment: It doesn't make sense to group by a column that is being summed. You can see from the question that the OP wants totals for rows with the same `noskom` value. Therefore, `noskom` is the column that the table needs to be grouped by. Take a look at the result of your query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9881/7) and you'll probably see your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query ::

```
select tbl2.id,tbl1.noskom,tbl1.sum1,tbl1.sum2,tbl1.sum3 from
(select id,noskom,sum(nonpbm) sum1,sum(noskop) sum2,sum(npbp) sum3 from tbl group by noskom) tbl1
 right join
(select id,null a,null b,null c,null d
from tbl) tbl2
on tbl1.id = tbl2.id
order by 1 ;
```